# Run WordPress on IIS with ASP.NET site

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, iis, iis-8.5

I am trying to run WordPress in Windows Server 2012 R2 and encountered an issue on displaying other WordPress pages except for the WordPress homepage.

The WordPress files are in ex. wordpress folder.

So the sites are accessible in; 
example.com/ – this returns successfully the ASP.NET website 
example.com/wordpress – this returns successfully the WordPress homepage website

But when I access different WordPress pages, ex. 
example.com/wordpress/about-us – I got an error saying

Server Error in ‘/’ Application. 
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /wordpress/about-us 
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2106.0

*Permalink is already setup with this setting 
example.com/wordpress/%postname%

*I also tried doing URL Rewrite on IIS Manager but it is not working. On the ASP.NET web.config it shows:

```
<rule name=”wordpress” enabled=”true” patternSyntax=”ECMAScript” stopProcessing=”true”>
    <match url=”(wordpress/about-us).*” />
    <action type=”Rewrite” url=”index.php” />
    <conditions logicalGrouping=”MatchAny”>
        <add input=”{REQUEST_FILENAME}” matchType=”IsFile” />
        <add input=”{REQUEST_FILENAME}” matchType=”IsDirectory” />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

WordPress Version: 5.6 
PHP Version: 7.3.24 
IIS Version: 8.5

Can someone help me?

Comment: This article seems to explain how to do it. In essence, the issue is likely that you didn't set up rewrite for wordpress site https://www.soupbowl.io/2020/01/the-complete-guide-to-running-wordpress-on-windows-iis/

Comment: I found that your logicalGrouping is MatchAny, it should be MatchAll. In addition to the methods they provide, you can also try to troubleshoot it. [https://blogs.iis.net/donraman/troubleshooting-php-installation-on-windows](https://blogs.iis.net/donraman/troubleshooting-php-installation-on-windows).

Comment: MikeSzyndel, samwu

you guys are right. By the way I posted an answer. :) Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is written in PHP. If you want to run WordPress in a windows machine (e.g. IIS) , you may set Module Mapping in your IIS manager after you have downloaded / installed PHP for windows.

For example, in the IIS Manager's Actions pane, you will be able to choose “Add Module Mapping.” Enter the necessary details to tell IIS that *.php files should be run by php-cgi.exe through FastCGI.

Comment: There are other important steps this answer didn't include. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-php#13-download-and-install-php-manually

Comment: Thanks guys for your inputs. These definitely helped me too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much for responding.

I was creating the Rewrite Rule on the wrong config file. Right now I created it on the “..the same directory where the WordPress files are installed..” as this guide in the link  below says.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress

For other’s reference:
web.config file path to create Rewrite Rule:
ex. C:\HostingSpaces\ASPWebsite\wordpress\web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```